# one array and multiple workers work and change on that array on matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have an array with `1xN` elements, and I want to use 4 or more workers (cores) to work, in parallel, on this array. Each worker takes some elements from that array and manipulate them. For example, `worker1` will take 3 elements, `worker2` will take the next 2 and so on. 
These workers will work in parallel.

How can these workers be synchronized to work well?
It seems like this would require a shared memory between multiple CPUs.

I need each worker read different size of data from that array at the same time: for example:

```
arr=1:100; % the common array 
serv1 = 3; % random numbers 
serv2 = 2; % random numbers 
serv3 = 1; % random numbers 
serv4 = 1; % random numbers
```

I need at the same time worker1 read `array(1:serv1)`, and worker 2 reads `array(serv1+1:serv1+serv2)` and worker3 reads `array(serv1+serv2+1:serv1+serv2+serv3)` and so on, and then manipulate the function on them

Comment: Do you have the Parallel Computing Toolbox ?

Comment: how exactly this implements shared memory, if each worker works on different elements of the array?

Comment: this will implement an M/M/n queue stystem , means one buffer and multiple servers, each server will take different element from the queue and serve it.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, I would propose something like this

```
n = numel(array); % this would be the common array
nw = 5; % number of workers, assuming you have at least that many workers up and running
start_i = floor(linspace(1,n,nw+1)); % each worker will start working from start_i 
start_i( end ) = [];
end_i = [start_i(2:end)+1 n]; % each worker will work till end_i
parfor ( ii = 1:nw, nw )
     processArray( array( start_i(ii):end_i(ii) ) ); % do your magic here
end
```

Comment: thank you for your response ... I need each worker read different size of data from that array at the same time: foe example:
arr=1:100; % the common array
serv1=3;
serv2=2;
serv3=1;
serv4=1;
% i NEED AT

Comment: thank you for your response ... I need each worker read different size of data from that array at the same time: foe example:
arr=1:100; % the common array
serv1=3;%random numbers
serv2=2;%random numbers
serv3=1;%random numbers
serv4=1;%random numbers
% I need ate the same time worker1 read array(1:serv1), and worker 2 reads array(serv1+1:serv1+serv2) and worker3 reads array(serv1+serv2+1:serv1+serv2+serv3) and so on, and then manipulate the function on them

Comment: @AbeerAwad - your comments are very important. PLEASE, edit your question accordingly - this way you'll get better answers.

Comment: @AbeerAwad - I'm afraid I do not have sufficient knowledge of parallel toolbox. Try looking at http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/labbroadcast.html I think this will help you solve the problem. If you come up with a method - don't forget to post it here as an answer!

Comment: can any one help me please?